# Backlinks from Redmine issues to wiki

Tags: redmine, wiki, redmine-plugins

Is there a plugin for backlinking from issues to wiki or documentation in Redmine?

For example:

```
1. Create a wiki page
2. Add an issue link in the wiki content: "#123"
3. View the issue #123 - you could see the Wiki page referenced under the issue including the page title
```

The closest I have found so far is probably this macro (haven't tested yet):
https://github.com/Yrwein/redmine_backlinks